# Why does " (.*?)$" will match " (abc abc)" in abc (abc abc)"?

Tags: regex, lazy-evaluation

Following my reasoning it should match a space > any chars before the end of the string, and `?` makes it lazy, meaning `abc)`? is the best match.

Why am I doing wrong? 
Shouldn't it match `abc)`?

Comment: The string is still evaluated from left to right. So the match starts at the first space. Lazy does not necessarily imply shortest.

Comment: It finds the first space and then everything after that matches. If you want to get everything after the last space, you should use `/ (\S*?)$/`

Answer (score 1):

It will find the first space and then everything else until the end of the string.

Because of the order of evaluation, this will get that first  (space) then your `(.*?)` will match everything until the end of the string `$`. This runs from left to right.

If you actually want to match anything after the last space, as pointed by @RevanProdigalKnight you will need to make sure it matches a space and then everything that is not a space until the end of the string. I will suggest the following regex:

```
/\s\S*$/
```

Comment: so, "?" does nothing here?

Comment: `*?` That's is a quantifier,  and it will match zero to unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed. The dot `.` matches also spaces.

Comment: @Kryoschdrmurgjencsen: Yes, the `?` has no effect.  Making a quantifier lazy/reluctant/non-greedy only affects where the match *ends*, not where it begins.  The `$` makes it irrelevant in this case, since it can only match the end of the string (leaving aside the distraction of Multiline and Singleline/DOTALL modes).

Answer (score 1):

Your regex:

```
 (.*?)$
```

or to make it more readable:

```
\s(.*?)$
```

is not really lazy as there is nothing **after** lazy quantifier `.*?`. It is pretty much same as:

```
\s(.*)$
```

that's why it is finding first space and everything after that space.